# Is there a way to PrependTo or AppendTo while flattening the result in the same step?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
arr = {1, 2, 3};
PrependTo[arr, {a, b}]

(* {{a, b}, 1, 2, 3} *)
```

But, I want

```
(* {a, b, 1, 2, 3} *)
```

I know I can use `Join` and do an assignment, but it seems odd to me that there isn't a way to assign in the same step, *e.g.* an option in `PrependTo` / `AppendTo`.

(A valid answer to this question would be: No, there's no way to avoid `Join` or `Flatten`.)

Comment: No, there's no way to avoid `Join` or `Flatten` or some equivalent incarnation. `PrependTo`  is *equivalent* precisely to `var=Prepend[var,ele]`, so since you're doing a mutation anyway, is there really a problem using `var=Flatten[{ele,var}]`, other than saving a few keystrokes? Just make a `myPPT` function to do it, then even that is nullified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no way to avoid Join or Flatten or some equivalent incarnation. Just roll your own if having the few extra keystrokes to do the mutation bothers you or you think it makes the code less pretty:

```
myPPT = Function[{a, b}, a = Flatten[{b, a}], HoldFirst];

myarr = {1, 2, 3};
myPPT[myarr, {9, 10}];
myarr
```

> {9,10,1,2,3}

Comment: I see, okay. It just seemed inconcise to write `paths[visited[node]] = Join[Most@path, paths[visited[node]]];`. Usually in $Mathematica$ I find I'm missing a shortcut, but in this case I guess not. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you want is a function called [`JoinTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JoinTo.html), which isn't built in, but it's easy to write

```
SetAttributes[JoinTo, HoldFirst];
JoinTo[list_, newlist_] := (list = Join[newlist, list]);
arr = {1, 2, 3};
JoinTo[arr, {a, b}];
arr
(* {a, b, 1, 2, 3} *)
```

But you said you wish to avoid `Join`, so let's try `CatenateTo`,

```
SetAttributes[CatenateTo, HoldFirst];
CatenateTo[list_, newlist_] := (list = Catenate[{newlist, list}]);
arr = {1, 2, 3};
CatenateTo[arr, {a, b}];
arr
(* {a, b, 1, 2, 3} *)
```

Comment: Yup, `JoinTo` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 2};
ReleaseHold@AppendTo[a, Hold@Sequence @@ {3, 4}]
```

or

```
Unprotect[{AppendTo, Append}];
Attributes[AppendTo] = {HoldFirst, SequenceHold};
Attributes[Append] = {SequenceHold};
AppendTo[a, Sequence @@ {3, 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For generality I'd use `Join` like:

```
arr = Join[{a,b}, arr]
```

you can create a function similarly to ciao's example.

---

Another method:

```
Activate @ PrependTo[arr, Inactive[Sequence][a, b]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {a, b};
```

Using `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2) and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
x //= Prepend @ Splice @ y;

x
```

{a, b, 1, 2, 3}

Turning this into functions is easy:

```
SetAttributes[JoinToFront, HoldAll]
JoinToFront[a_, b_] := a //= Prepend @ Splice @ b;
```

Apply:

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {a, b};

JoinToFront[x, y];
x
```

{a, b, 1, 2, 3}

```
SetAttributes[JoinToBack, HoldAll]
JoinToBack[a_, b_] := a //= Append @ Splice @ b;
```

Apply:

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {a, b};

JoinToBack[x, y];
x
```

{1, 2, 3, a, b}

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = {1, 2, 3};

PrependTo[arr, Splice @ {a, b}];

arr
```

> ```
> {a, b, 1, 2, 3}
> ```

```
WolframLanguageData["Splice", {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image: > {12.1, DateObject[{2020, 3, 18}, "Day"]}]

Answer (score 1):

Using `Tally` and `Splice` we can build the following function:

```
JoinToEitherEnd[l1_, l2_, opts : (Automatic | "ToBack") : Automatic] := 
  Module[
    {front, back},
    front = Map[Function[Splice[Part[#, All, 1]]],
            Map[Tally, Reverse @ {l1, l2}]
        ];
    back = Map[Function[Splice[Part[#, All, 1]]],
            Map[Tally, {l1, l2}]
        ];
    Switch[
            opts, Automatic,
                front, "ToBack",
                back
        ]
   ];

JoinToEitherEnd[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b}]

(*{a, b, 1, 2, 3}*)

JoinToEitherEnd[arr, {a, b}, "ToBack"]

(*{1, 2, 3, a, b}*)
```

Or using `Insert` and `Splice`:

```
Insert[{1, 2, 3}, Splice@{a, b}, 1]

(*{a, b, 1, 2, 3}*)

Insert[{1, 2, 3}, Splice@{a, b}, -1]

(*{1, 2, 3, a, b}*)
```